# memory allocation never change for my virtual machine

Tags: memory, libvirt, virt-manager

I setup the memory allocation for my guest thru virt-manager.
I set 16384Mb for the current memory and 32768Mb for the max memory.
I note that the current memory never change ! why ?

In the same way, I set the cpu number to 2 but the vm uses ALWAYS only one.

host: Debian/Jessie
guest: ws2012
libvirt version: 1.2.9
virt-manager: 1.0.1
Driver ballon for windows: version 62.73.104.12600/11.8.2016

Comment: Are you completely shutting down the guest OS before you make changes? If you merely suspend, the OS will resume with the same settings it was booted wth.

Comment: sure and several times !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't mention which hypervisor you're using, so I'm going to guess KVM, but my answer applies to Xen too. When you set currentMemory=16384 and maxMemory=32768, you are telling KVM to boot with 32 GB of RAM and use balloon driver to reduce that to 16 GB.

Once the balloon driver has reduced the RAM to 16 GB, it will never be increased again unless you explicitly tell KVM to increase. It won't adjust itself without you telling it to

WRT to the CPU count - you don't mention if you set the CPU count to 2 before booting the guest, or while it was already running. Generally most OS want you set the CPU count before booting it, as they don't automatically hot-plug CPUs.

There's a further complication with some versions of Windows - if you only have 1 CPU when you first install Windows, then even if you later add CPUs they won't be used since Windows was installed in single-processor mode. In addition some versions of windows only support a single socket, but allow multiple cores. So you might need to tell virt-manager to change CPU topology to expose 1 socket with 2 cores, instead of 2 sockets with 1 core.

Comment: exact. I use KVM-qemu and I set the CPU count before booting. I also set copy of the host CPU config.

Comment: I don't see/understand the utility of the balloon mechanism if this one is not able to attribute more memory when the other vm are "quiet"

Comment: I read this on the KVM site: The balloon has to be automatic in order to be really useful. It could like this: when the host is under pressure, it asks guests to relinquish some megas if they can. When/if a guest gets into memory pressure, it gets some megas back from the host. That's what the automatic ballooning series is about.

Comment: Shall I understand that today auto-ballooning is not yet implemented in KVM-qemu and libvirt ?

Comment: Correct, that text you read is just describing some future wishlist item. Currently you have to manually change the balloon level on guests

Comment: The utility of this feature is that you can adjust the RAM of the VM without having to reboot it. I find that incredibly useful at times. Of course some automatic adjustment would be very useful, but there won't ever be a one size fits it all kind of logic to distribute the available memory to the VMs, so probably they intentionally left that to be beyond the scope of libvirt. It's likely that other software that builds on top of libvirt actually implements it.